# Is this solution for this system of differencial equation correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following system of difference equation:

$$ y_{t+1} = y_t - 9z_t $$
$$ z_{t+1} = y_t - 5z_t $$

I have to find the specific solution satisfying $$y_0 = 2, z_0 = -2$$

---

I tried to apply the following procedure.

First of all I have to find the general solution. So Matrix A is equal to:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -9 \\ 1 & -5\end{pmatrix}
$$

So:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 - \lambda & -9 \\ 1 & -5 - \lambda \end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore by equaling the determinant to $0$ I obtain $\lambda = -2$.

Therefore the characteristic equation is equal to:
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -9 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}

I then obtain the following eigenvector:
$$
\vec{v}_1 =
\begin{vmatrix}
3\\ 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

By equaling the characteristic equation to the eigenvector $\vec{v}_1$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -9 & 3 \\ 
1 & -3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I obtain the second eigenvalues:
\begin{equation}
\vec{v}_2 =
\begin{vmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

Finally, the general solution is equal to:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
y_t\\ 
z_t
\end{vmatrix}
=
C_1 \lambda^t \vec{v}_1 + C_2 \lambda^t 
\left (
\vec{v}_2 + \frac{1}{\lambda}t \vec{v}_1
 \right )
$$

That is the general solution is the following:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
y_t\\ z_t
\end{vmatrix}
=
C_1 (-2)^t 
\begin{vmatrix}
3\\ 1
\end{vmatrix}
 + C_2 (-2)^t
\left (
\begin{vmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{vmatrix}
 - \frac{1}{2}t
\begin{vmatrix}
3\\ 1
\end{vmatrix}
\right )
$$

But I know that in that in the general solution there are no rational numbers so the solution I found is not correct.
What is my mistake?

Comment: there is just one eigenvector. Have you had Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: yes I computed it and I obtain 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1\\  0 & -2 
\end{pmatrix} $$
but I don't know what is its usefulness...

Comment: zcb, what would be solutions for a new system, $w_{t+1} = -2 w_t + x_t$ and $x_{t+1} = -2 x_t \; ? \; $

Comment: I don't know, why are you asking me this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "there's no rational numbers in the general solution." Your difference system sends integers to integers, so having a fully rational general solution hardly seems objectionable.

Comment: Because your original system depends on it. There is a constant matrix such that your $(y_t, z_t)^{Transpose} = P ( w_t, x_t)^{Transpose} $

Comment: @Semiclassical pretty clear he has never gone as far as finding $P^{-1}AP = J$ in Jordan form and using $P$ and $P^{-1}$ in the problems. I try to get the students here to work out actual matrices $P.$  There is a method, not always taught, that is pretty simple when matrix elements and eigenvalues are all integers.

Comment: @WillJagy That's probably correct, but the upshot of my question is that there doesn't actually seem anything wrong with the proposed final solution.

Comment: @Semiclassical I apologize for not expressing myself well. I mean, I know that in the general solution no rational number appears so that $$ - \frac {1}{2} t $$ multiplied by $$ \begin{vmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{vmatrix} $$
it is wrong because the first multiplication is $$ - \frac{3}{2}t $$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for your contribution, but am I wrong or to write the general solution you only need to know lambda and the eigenvectors?
If so, I already got these in the process I wrote. I am wrong?

Comment: I guess that is enough. Carefully work out your constants $C_1, C_2$ and  write it all together

Comment: Ok thanks again, so why should I compute the Jordan form when I task this problem if I don't need it to get the solution?